# get user from belongsToMany relationships

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have a `service` model in **October CMS**.

In this model, I need to get `postman`'s users (`postman` is user group) but I am receiving this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

This is my code

```
public function getPostmanIdOptions()
{

    $groups = UserGroup::where('id','4')->lists('name', 'id');
    $groups->users;

    $list = [' ' => 'choose'] + $groups;
    return $list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, your `lists()` function will only return the `name` and the `id` of each user group. This is used to return thelselect options for the backend select (I am assuming).

What you need to do in this case is return the record based on its `id` which can be done using the `find()` eloquent method.

By doing this, the full `UserGroup` model will be returned, with it's relationships etc.

You're new code should look something like this:

```
...    

$group = UserGroup::find(4);
$users = $group->users;

...
```

After retrieving the `users`, you can then using the `lists()` method if required to:

```
$list = $group->users->lists('name', 'id');
```